# Mulesoft: Default value for not existing deep nodes

Tags: mule

I use Data Weave to transform XML and have issue with not existing nodes. For example xml

```
<a>
   <b>
      <c>
         value
      </c>
   </b>
</a>
```

Extracted { one: $.a, two: $a.b, three: $a.b.c } It works fine when all nodes a,b and c exist.

What would be the way to determine when node b is empty and have default value for node c?

This is really simply example. Real data has a lot of deepness levels and each level could be empty. Maybe I should use when/otherwise but then I should repeat whole data structure for each variable.

[image]

Here is Mule flow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:metadata="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/metadata" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd">
    <flow name="xml2flatFlow" doc:description="To run copy src/main/resources/*.xml files to src/test/resources/FileIn
Good working example is xml_in_good.xml

Issues:

1) Should be working with Streams but from Json2Flat there is no way to FileOut. &quot;Load everything to memory&quot; is required but it kills stream. What is the way to make it Stream and work with huge files?

2) FlatFile field have particular length. Transformation should cut the length. Instead it produces exception. Should be option oe way to force the length of the string.
Example: xml_in_bad_too_long.xml

3) Main issue - I cannot figure out how process empty nodes. 
Example: xml_in_bad.xml

Provided example is simlpiest. In reality I have very long xpath like payload.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h
I tried to do when/otherwise, default, h?, internal Java program - nothing works.

I believe that processor File2Json is not necessary but I'd added it to make sure XML processor have no influence on the flow. ">
        <file:inbound-endpoint path="src\test\resources\FileIn" moveToDirectory="src\test\resources\FileProcessed" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FileIn"/>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="24cbc998-ba7d-44f7-a3fa-cb502d352e87" doc:name="File2Json">
            <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/xml"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="15c2b229-fb5a-4430-be89-c446e79bfa2e" doc:name="Json2Json">
            <dw:input-payload doc:sample="C:\Users\Alex\AnypointStudio6\workspace\xml2flat\src\main\resources\too_long.json" mimeType="application/json"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
{
    a: payload.a default {},
    b: payload.a.b default {},
    c: payload.a.b.c default ""
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <dw:transform-message metadata:id="8ef7c277-ec47-4564-9ece-eac11c27c891" doc:name="Json2Flat">
            <dw:input-payload doc:sample="C:\Users\Alex\AnypointStudio6\workspace\xml2flat\src\main\resources\too_long.json"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output text/plain schemaPath = "flatfile.ffd" , segmentIdent = ""
---
[{
    field_0: payload.c default "---"
}]]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Load everythin to memory"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="src/test/resources/FileOut" outputPattern="out.txt" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="FileOut"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Here is log:

```
*******************************************************************************************************
* xml2flatSO                                    * default                        * DEPLOYED           *
*******************************************************************************************************

INFO  2016-09-30 13:57:29,271 [[xml2flatSO].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\Users\Alex\AnypointStudio6\workspace\xml2flatSO\src\test\resources\FileIn\xml_in_good.xml
INFO  2016-09-30 13:57:37,892 [[xml2flatSO].xml2flatFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: {
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": "GOOD"
    }
  }
}
INFO  2016-09-30 13:57:42,334 [[xml2flatSO].connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Initialising: 'connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.546298364'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
INFO  2016-09-30 13:57:42,334 [[xml2flatSO].connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.lifecycle.AbstractLifecycleManager: Starting: 'connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.546298364'. Object is: FileMessageDispatcher
INFO  2016-09-30 13:57:42,335 [[xml2flatSO].connector.file.mule.default.dispatcher.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileConnector: Writing file to: C:\Users\Alex\AnypointStudio6\workspace\xml2flatSO\src\test\resources\FileOut\out.txt
INFO  2016-09-30 13:57:52,448 [[xml2flatSO].connector.file.mule.default.receiver.01] org.mule.transport.file.FileMessageReceiver: Lock obtained on file: C:\Users\Alex\AnypointStudio6\workspace\xml2flatSO\src\test\resources\FileIn\xml_in_bad.xml
INFO  2016-09-30 13:57:55,979 [[xml2flatSO].xml2flatFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: {
  "a": ""
}
ERROR 2016-09-30 13:58:16,403 [[xml2flatSO].xml2flatFlow.stage1.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Exception while executing: 
    b: payload.a.b default {},
       ^
Type mismatch for 'Value Selector' operator
     found :string, :name
  required :datetime, :name or
  required :localdatetime, :name or
  required :object, :name or
  required :time, :name or
  required :array, :name or
  required :date, :name or
  required :localtime, :name or
  required :period, :name
Payload               : {
  "a": ""
}
Payload Type          : java.lang.String
Element               : /xml2flatFlow/processors/3 @ xml2flatSO:xml2flat.xml:37 (Json2Json)
Element XML           : <dw:transform-message metadata:id="15c2b229-fb5a-4430-be89-c446e79bfa2e" doc:name="Json2Json">
                        <dw:input-payload doc:sample="C:\Users\Alex\AnypointStudio6\workspace\xml2flat\src\main\resources\too_long.json" mimeType="application/json"></dw:input-payload>
                        <dw:set-payload>%dw 1.0%output application/json---{a: payload.a default {},b: payload.a.b default {},c: payload.a.b.c default ""}</dw:set-payload>
                        </dw:transform-message>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.dynamic.UnexpectedOperationTypesException: Type mismatch for 'Value Selector' operator
     found :string, :name
  required :datetime, :name or
  required :localdatetime, :name or
  required :object, :name or
  required :time, :name or
  required :array, :name or
  required :date, :name or
  required :localtime, :name or
  required :period, :name
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.OpNode$class.doExecuteAutoCoercion(OpNode.scala:79)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.BinaryOpNode.doExecuteAutoCoercion(BinaryOpNode.scala:8)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.OpNode$class.doExecute(OpNode.scala:33)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.BinaryOpNode.doExecute(BinaryOpNode.scala:8)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.ValueNode$class.execute(AstNode.scala:38)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.BinaryOpNode.execute(BinaryOpNode.scala:8)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.selectors.NullSafeNode.doExecute(NullSafeNode.scala:16)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.ValueNode$class.execute(AstNode.scala:38)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.selectors.NullSafeNode.execute(NullSafeNode.scala:10)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.conditional.DefaultNode.doExecute(DefaultNode.scala:13)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.ValueNode$class.execute(AstNode.scala:38)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.conditional.DefaultNode.execute(DefaultNode.scala:10)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.structure.KeyValuePairNode.doExecute(KeyValuePairNode.scala:12)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.ValueNode$class.execute(AstNode.scala:38)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.structure.KeyValuePairNode.execute(KeyValuePairNode.scala:10)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.structure.ObjectNode$$anonfun$4.apply(DynamicObjectNode.scala:39)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.structure.ObjectNode$$anonfun$4.apply(DynamicObjectNode.scala:38)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.structure.ObjectNode.doExecute(DynamicObjectNode.scala:38)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.ValueNode$class.execute(AstNode.scala:38)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.structure.ObjectNode.execute(DynamicObjectNode.scala:28)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.ValueNode$class.write(AstNode.scala:28)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.ast.structure.ObjectNode.write(DynamicObjectNode.scala:28)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.Engine.write(Engine.scala:165)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.Engine.execute(Engine.scala:88)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.engine.Engine.execute(Engine.scala:103)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.debug.DebugWeaveExecutorStrategy$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(DebugWeaveExecutorStrategy.scala:30)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.debug.DebugWeaveExecutorStrategy$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(DebugWeaveExecutorStrategy.scala:28)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.debug.DebugWeaveExecutorStrategy.execute(DebugWeaveExecutorStrategy.scala:28)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor.execute(WeaveMessageProcessor.scala:117)
    at com.mulesoft.weave.mule.WeaveMessageProcessor.process(WeaveMessageProcessor.scala:65)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.processNextTimed(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:123)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:208)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker$1.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:201)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:30)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor$AsyncMessageProcessorWorker.doRun(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:200)
    at org.mule.work.AbstractMuleEventWork.run(AbstractMuleEventWork.java:53)
    at org.mule.work.WorkerContext.run(WorkerContext.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

********************************************************************************
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had open issue case with Mulesoft and they provided this suggestion which works.
Some property should be added to Dataweave then it works as desired.

```
<dw:reader-property name="nullValueOn" value="blank" />
```

All three cases do work no matter how much data is provided **a.b.c** or **a.b** or **a** or nothing at all.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
 {  one: payload.a, 
    two: payload.a.b default "y", 
    three: payload.a.b.c default "x"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use default keyword something like

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
 {  one: payload.a, 
    two: payload.a.b default "y", 
    three: payload.a.b.c default "x"
 }
```

Input:-

```
<a>
    <c>value</c>
</a>
```

Output

```
{
  "one": {
    "c": "value"
  },
  "two": "y",
  "three": "x"
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good approach but if b is not present DW produces error. My actual xpath is like payload.a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h and any of these links could be absent.

Comment: Which version is used. Cause for me DW is working fine even if b is absent.

Comment: Latest one. Version: 6.1.1
Build Id: 201609131828

Try the same example but with input <a/> only.

Comment: Please try this.. `%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
 {  one: payload.a, 
  two: payload.*a.b default "Y", 
  three: payload.*a.b.c default "x"
 } `. This should work. Let me know if you face any issues.

Comment: @Alex , have you tied * like `payload.*a.b.c default "x"` mentioned in comments.